# Npm run dev stuck at APP_URL

Tags: laravel, npm, breeze

I created a new laravel project, installed breeze auth and ran npm install and npm run dev. But it's stuck at this screen for 15 minutes now. Nothing is moving on the terminal window.

All the commands I used was

```
laravel new shop
composer require laravel/breeze
php artisan breeze:install
npm install
npm run dev
```

Everything worked fine until npm run dev, but when I enter npm run dev command, I get this output and nothing else.

```
PS C:\shop> npm run dev

> dev
> vite

  vite v2.9.13 dev server running at:

  > Local: http://localhost:3000/
  > Network: use `--host` to expose

  ready in 364ms.


  Laravel v9.19.0

  > APP_URL: http://shop.test
```

Comment: php artisan view:clear

Comment: It said "Compiled views cleared successfully." I ran run dev again and it's stuck at the same place again.

Comment: Remove "laravel/breeze": "^1.10", from your composer.json and run command: composer update. After that check your nodejs and npm version and install breeze again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel version 9.19.0 replaced Mixer with Vite for more information check [Bundling Assets (Vite)](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite)

if you want to work mixer install Laravel version /= 9.1.0

`composer create-project Laravel/Laravel app_name 9.1.0`

Answer (score 2):

I used npm run build instead npm run dev. And that solved it, I guess.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks bot, but I'm new to laravel and even I don't know why it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. I tried for many hours to solve this problem. Laravel 9.19.0+ is using Vite to replace Laravel Mix for bundling assets. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#main-content

Starter kit components like Laravel Breeze and Jetstream have been using `@vite`

```
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
```

When we run `npm run dev` vite will create own host below.

```
> dev
> vite

vite v2.9.13 dev server running at:

> Local: http://localhost:3000/
> Network: use `--host` to expose

ready in 364ms.


Laravel v9.19.0

> APP_URL: http://shop.test
```

And alway embed our style and script with this host `http://127.0.0.1:3000/`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:3000/resources/css/app.css">
<script type="module" src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/resources/js/app.js"></script>
```

I found a file name `hot` in the folder `public` was been created during we run command `npm run dev` and it is never delete.

To work around I just delete `hot` file by add few code into `package.json`

**From**

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
},
```

**To**

```
"scripts": {
    "delhot": "npx rimraf public/hot",
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "npm run delhot vite build"
},
```

I hope that next release version of Laravel Vite will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

composer create-project Laravel/Laravel app_name 9.1.0
Just use this laravel ver

Answer (score 0):

The below solkution worked for me,
Check laravel Logs, there might be issue you are not importing all files in your vite.cofing.js,
Just for example in my app.blade im am using

```
 @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
    @vite('resources/css/app.css')
    @vite('resources/css/extra.css')
    @vite('resources/css/partical.css')
    @vite('resources/css/scroll.css')
    @vite('resources/css/faqs.css')
    @vite('resources/css/animate.css')
```

---

### so in my vite.config.js,  i have to add these, suppose in case you have 2 vite.config.js and vite.config.js.timestamp , you have to add in both

export default defineConfig({

```
 plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/css/partical.css',
                'resources/css/scroll.css',
                'resources/css/faqs.css',
                'resources/css/animate.css',
                "resources/css/extra.css",
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

---

in my package.json

```
"scripts": {
        "delhot": "npx rimraf public/hot",
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "npm run delhot && vite build"
    },
```

This solution worked for me, my app.css was not showing in frontend source code